# How to mock an instance variable in nested class

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, instagram

#### Simplified Example:

```
def bind_method(**config):
    class InstagramAPIMethod(object):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.return_json = kwargs.pop("return_json", False)
    def _call(*args, **kwargs):
        method = InstagramAPIMethod(*args, **kwargs)
        return method.__dict__

    return _call

class InstAPI():
  result = bind_method(foo='bar')

api = InstAPI()
print api.result()

# {'return_json': False}
```

From the above example are there any ways to "monkey patch" an "InstAPI" instance or use "partial" function to hardcode the value to "_call" function in such a way so that it would return `{'return_json': True}` ?

#### Reallife Example:

https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram.git

If you look at the https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram/blob/master/instagram/bind.py#L42-L69

You will see `bind_method` function that looks like this:

```
def bind_method(**config):
  class InstagramAPIMethod(object):
    path = config['path']
    method = config.get('method', 'GET')
```

In https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram/blob/master/instagram/bind.py#L64 line there is a parameter. I can't find a clear way how to change it to `True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) give to you some way to do it. The case is little bit tricky because

1. `InstagramAPIMethod` is defined in `bind_method` function
2. `InstAPI` store `bind_method` definition at load time

So patch `bind_method` or `InstagramAPIMethod` class have no effect. You have just a chance: patch `InstAPI.result`. I've take in account of 2 case:

1. I don't care of the work in `bind_method` and I need just that `api.result()` return a dictionary like `{'return_json': True}`
2. I would like that `result()` return exactly what `bind_method` return except changing some values

Following the code for the toy example that should work also in the real life.

```
def bind_method(**config):
    class InstagramAPIMethod(object):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.return_json = kwargs.pop("return_json", False)
    def _call(*args, **kwargs):
        method = InstagramAPIMethod(*args, **kwargs)
        return method.__dict__
    return _call

class InstAPI():
  result = bind_method(foo='bar')

api = InstAPI()
print api.result()


from mock import patch
#Patch directly InstAPI.result
with patch("__main__.InstAPI.result",return_value={'return_json': True}):
    api = InstAPI()
    print api.result()

#The wrapper of bind_method
def new_instapi_result(**kwargs):
    def functor(**config):
        d = bind_method(**config)()
        d.update(kwargs)
        return d
    return functor

#Patch and wrap bind_method
with patch("__main__.InstAPI.result",side_effect=new_instapi_result(return_json = True)):
    api = InstAPI()
    print api.result()
```

Comment: Wow, that's smart. Thank you very much. The wrapper function is definitely what I was looking for. But I'm struggling to understand what do I need to patch in real example. I've tried `pathc('instagram.client.bind_method')` but it seems to have no affect.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer patch `bind_method` is useless because when you assign it to `result` you store the original one and not a reference. Maybe if you change `result=bind_method(foo='bar')` in `result=lambda:bind_method(foo='bar')` it works. Anyway why don't patch `InstAPI.result` by the wrapper in the last example?

Comment: I think that's because class `InstAPI` calls `bind_method` with additional parameters (`foo='bar'`).  And I'm not sure if they are getting passed.

Comment: I wrote something wrong: `result` must be  `lambda **kwargs:bind_method(foo='bar')(**kwargs)`. Anyway, is `InstAPI` a your api? Can you change it? If you don't you can add at the top of your test module a line like `InstAPI.result=lambda **kwargs:bind_method(foo='bar')(**kwargs)` and now you can patch `bind_method` because you call it when you call result.